# Can I able to get file version information of an exe file without using FileVersionInfo?

Tags: c#

I am able to get the file version information through the namespace FileVersionInfo in  C#. In FileVersionInfo, if file version is empty then we aren't able to get other information like product version, company name etc. I can see the file version information when we right click the file and select the details tab in Properties window but i can't get the value through C# code. So Can I get file version information without using FileVersionInfo? Are there any other ways to get the file version information.

Comment: This nuget package can help you: [WindowsAPICodePack](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAPICodePack-Core/), there are barely any documentations.

Answer (score 3):

Try this :-

```
   Assembly assembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(@"D:\exePath\yourexe.exe");
   Version ver = assembly.GetName().Version;
```

Comment: This will return the assembly version but not the file version.

Answer (score 0):

To get the file version you have to get the Version set by the `AssemblyFileVersionAttribute`, for example like this:

```
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("3.2.10.0")]
```

Here is the code of an extension method to read the attribute:

```
    public static Version GetFileVersion(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        AssemblyFileVersionAttribute attribute = assembly.GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyFileVersionAttribute>();
        return attribute == null ? null : new Version(attribute.Version);
    }
```

To load the assembly use the `Assembly.LoadFrom` method as mentioned before.

Comment: BTW: Loading an assembly with `Assembly.LoadFrom` will only work with .NET exe files.

Comment: But i need get the file version information for my Delphi EXE files. Please let me know any other namespace or methods like fileversioninfo in C#?